# Python: checking to see if a value is a certain object

Tags: python, object, types, instanceof

I know if the `isinstance()` method, which can be used to check if a value is a certain type. For instance,

```
num = 3
print isinstance(num, int)
```

Gives us `True`.

I have a custom made object now, called `Project`. `Project` has some attributes that are specific. One of my methods uses a `Project` as a parameter, and I want to validate that the input parameter is indeed of type `Project`. Will the same method work?

Comment: why dont you try that yourself

Comment: You could have tested this in less time than it took to post this question!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`isinstance(obj, Project)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) is the correct way to see if `obj` is an instance of `Project`, even if `Project` is a custom class.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the formatting in this comment. See below...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
class A:
    pass

print(isinstance(A(), A))
```

prints "True".

Answer (score 0):

The function works well.

```
class A:
    #some code

X=A()
if(isinstance(X, A)):
    print "hello"
```

prints `hello`